# Vue 3 router with docker compose isn't working

Tags: typescript, docker, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

i want to ask why my vue3 route while using it with docker-compose doesn't work but the homepage still work ?

here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server
# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app
# copy 'package.json' to install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
# install dependencies
RUN npm install
# copy files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .
# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build
COPY ./commonfiles/.htaccess ./dist
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

and here's my docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

```
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - myapp-network
networks:
  myapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

i've been trying to add .htaccess in dist folder but the result still same when i tried to access myapp.test/login, it's still gimme error 404 page but the homepage still work.

i hope anyone can help me, been like hours finding the solution in google but still giving me the same result.

****note : i run this in my local machine and i've tested the code without docker the vue router works properly***